# Prevent users to read an entire collection in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection with around 30 thousands documents. My security rules are configured so that only authenticated users can read such documents from this collection. I cannot add more constraints regarding read operations for this specific collection. 
When using my app, up to 50 documents are averagely returned, depending on the query.
Is there any way to prevent a malicious user to download the entire collection in Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the number of documents a user can read at once, you can [include a limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) in your security rules as shown in the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query):

```
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 50;
```

Keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters), so the application code will also need to include this (or a lower) limit in its code.